# How to make api request to Github repository using restapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, rest

I am new to C# and .Net and I am struggling to understand this issue that I have. I feel like what I have is enough but not sure myself. SO if someone can just review the codes that I have below and tell me were to correct and what is wrong.Thank you

This is my Model Class

```
namespace github_project.Models
{
    public class GithubItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string Commits { get; set; }
        public double Rating { get; set; }
        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is my database context

```
namespace github_project.Database
{
    public class GithubContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<GithubItem> Github { get; set; }
        public GithubContext(DbContextOptions<GithubContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public GithubItem ItemsList()
        {
            List<GithubItem> build = Build();
            GithubItem itemsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GithubItem>(build);
            return itemsList;
        }

        public List<GithubItem> Build()
        {
            var getData = GetGithubData();
            return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GithubItem>>(getData);
        }

        private string GetGithubData()
        {
            string username = "**test**";
            var url = "https://api.github.com/users/" + username + "/repos?page=1";

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.UserAgent = "TestApp";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        public List<GithubItem> getGithub() => Github.Local.ToList<GithubItem>();
    }
}
```

finally this is my controller

```
[HttpGet("/github")]
public GithubItem GetAll()
{
    return _context.ItemsList();
}
```

I am making a request to github in order to get all the data and use it in my request. I am getting an here here of converting Collection.List to String on this method below:

```
public GithubItem ItemsList()
{
    List<GithubItem> build = Build();
    GithubItem itemsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GithubItem>(**build**);
    return itemsList;
}
```

Can someone help me and and someone tell me what is wrong here??? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot deserialize an object or convert an object from `List<GithubItem>` to single `GithubItem`. That is what you are doing.

As you can see, you have `build`:

```
List<GithubItem> build = Build();
```

This `build` variable is a `List<GithubItem`. Now you want to convert it to single using Deserialize of JsonConvert?

You can just get one record, whatever your requirements is using this code:

```
 GithubItem itemsList = build.FirstOrDefault();
```

That would build fine. But this is just an example since I am not sure what is your requirement. If you need to filter your record, you can also pass a argument on FirstOrDefault:

```
 GithubItem itemsList = build.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "John");
```

That would also work fine.